# Entity Framework - Get Scalar

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a GetScalar method. We use a lot of DataTables in the legacy systems. I'm converting them to EF.

Here's the goal. This is a simple method that takes a Stored Procedure name and parameters, then returns the First Row, First Column of the result set.

```
public object GetScalar(string command, CommandType type = CommandType.StoredProcedure, List<SqlParameter> parameterList = null)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(command, cnn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = type;

                    if (parameterList != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var p in parameterList)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
                        }
                    }

                    cmd.Connection.Open();
                    object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    cmd.Connection.Close();
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    return obj;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logging.LogError(ex, "MSSqlUtility.GetScalar");
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

I'd like to have a similar method in EF. Here's what I have so far, but this returns all columns - not just the first.

```
protected T SelectScalar<T>(string inStoredProcedure, ICollection<SqlParameter> inParameters = null)
    {
        T result = default(T);
        if (inParameters != null && inParameters.Count > 0)
        {
            string paramNames = string.Join(",", inParameters.Select(parameter => parameter.ParameterName).ToList());
            string sqlString = inStoredProcedure + " " + paramNames;
            object[] paramValues = inParameters.Cast<object>().ToArray();               
            result = Database.SqlQuery<T>(sqlString, paramValues).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            result = Database.SqlQuery<T>(inStoredProcedure).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return result;
}
```

Example usage. This returns a string object - "John Doe".

```
public string GetUserName(string employeeID)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(employeeID))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var parameters = new Collection<SqlParameter>();            
        parameters.Add(StoredProcedureParameterBuilder.StringParam("@EmployeeID", employeeID, 20));
        return this.SelectScalar<string>("dbo.GetUserName", parameters).Trim();
    }
```

The SQL query looks something like this:

```
SELECT 
    FirstName + ' ' + Last Name
,EmployeeID
FROM Users
```

Changing the stored procedure isn't an option - we need both columns in other contexts. The current code returns both the name **and the ID**. I'd like to fetch just the first column, first row, of whatever my query may spit back.

Comment: can you add an example of how this method is being used and what the result looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up having to do a bit more manual work. If anyone has a better solution, I'm all ears, but this works for my use case:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Selects the first item in the query's result.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="inStoredProcedure">The in stored procedure.</param>
    /// <param name="inParameters">The in parameters.</param>
    /// <returns>The first object in the specified type T.</returns>
    protected T SelectScalar<T>(string inStoredProcedure, ICollection<SqlParameter> inParameters = null)
    {            
        using (System.Data.IDbCommand command = Database.Connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            try
            {                   
                command.CommandText = inStoredProcedure;
                command.CommandTimeout = command.Connection.ConnectionTimeout;

                if(inParameters != null &&  inParameters.Count > 0)
                {
                    string paramNames = string.Join(",", inParameters.Select(parameter => parameter.ParameterName).ToList());
                    command.CommandText += " " + paramNames;
                    foreach (var param in inParameters)
                    {
                        command.Parameters.Add(param);
                    }
                }

                Database.Connection.Open();
                return (T)command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            finally
            {
                Database.Connection.Close();
                command.Parameters.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess that works, but it isn't really using Entity Framework at all.

Comment: Good point. After some analysis, EF won't work for our usage. Queries from a single table are fine, but as soon as you start joining other tables, EF gets pretty complex pretty quickly.